# Keybinding conditional on cursor location?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor

How do I bind a key to do one thing at the beginning of the line, and another thing everywhere else?

I would like to ask about the possibility that pressing the `<home>` key when the cursor is at the beginning of the current line, results in the execution of a certain function or command (say `myfunction1`) and otherwise results in the execution of other function or command (say `myfunction2`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a command that will do one thing when at the beginning of the line, and do another when not there.  You can then bind it to your key of choice.  Example:

```
(defun message-me ()
  (interactive)
  (if (bolp)
      (message "At beginning of line")
    (message "Not at beginning of line")))

(global-set-key [home] #'message-me)
```

Comment: This idea can be used to provide a very simple alternative solution to http://stackoverflow.com/a/25587659/3170376.

Comment: @Name True. I've seen similar commands to replace the standard C-a and C-e bindings, e.g. to have C-a go to the beginning of the current line or if already there go up a line.

Answer (score 5):

@Dan's suggestion of using a dispatch command is probably the best approach.

Here is another, that can be useful in some contexts. But it is probably not what you want for the general case you cite, of doing something special at the beginning of any line, anywhere.

You can put a `keymap` text property on a character in a buffer. Its value is a keymap. Any keys you bind in that keymap take precedence. So when the cursor is just before that character, hitting a key bound in that map invokes its command.

So in your use case (but again, this is probably not what you want to do, unless you want the behavior only in particular contexts, e.g. particular buffers or zones of text), you would add a key binding using a `keymap` text property on the first char of each line where you wanted it.

See the Elisp manual, node [`Special Properties`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html).

Comment: Wow!  Again, it's posts like this that make me love this site.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to use menu-item:

```
(defun my-at-beg-of-line ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Only at beg of line"))

(global-set-key
 [home]
 '(menu-item "" nil :filter
             (lambda
               (&optional _)
               (if (bolp)
                   'my-at-beg-of-line
                 'beginning-of-line))))
```

This has the advantage that `C-h k` gives you the documentation of the command
which would be triggered in current context and you can use distinct commands instead of mixing the decision code with the execution code like in the accepted answer.